# AngularJS: look inside Watch List

Tags: angularjs

I want to `investigate the content of the Watch List`, to see which items are inside as to be watched. Is that possible and how may I achieve that? Consider the following code:

```
<html ng-app="scopeExample">

<div ng-controller="MyController">
  Your name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="username">
    <button ng-click='sayHello()'>greet</button>
  <hr>
  {{greeting}}
</div>

<script>
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
}]);
</script>   

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
$scope.$$watchers
```

Comment: By trying `console.log($scope.$$watchers)` I am getting **null**. What do I have to do with the above code as to see something?

Comment: See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jqjyvdjx/. Note that there are some empty watchers - it's ok.